# iPhone SDK 6 Launching maps with voice navigation directions

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-location, ios5

I am trying to launch the maps app from my iPhone SDK app.  Right now I can launch the maps app with directions but it goes to an overview of the directions and doesn't use Siri and the voice navigation to give turn by turn directions.

currently I have a button that launches this code...

```
NSString *address = viewedObject.addressFull;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@", here.latitude, here.longitude, [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With iOS 6 there's a new way to launch maps, using `openMapsWithItems:` in `MKMapItem`.  Here's a snippet that I use that provides walking or driving directions from current location to the provided coordinates:

```
// iOS 6.0+ only
MKPlacemark* destPlace = [[[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
MKMapItem* destMapItem = [[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destPlace] autorelease]; destMapItem.name = stationItem.title;

NSArray* mapItems = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destMapItem, nil] autorelease];
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 walking ? MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                                 MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];
```

The way you are doing it, which you still have to do if running on pre-iOS 6 devices, you need to include the `dirflg` in the URL to request walking or driving directions:

```
// pre iOS 6 code
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&dirflg=%c",
    currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,
    currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,
    destination.coordinate.latitude,
    destination.coordinate.longitude,
    walking ? 'w' : 'd'];
```

Comment: thanks for your help...the iOS 6.0+ only was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I tried it but was unable to see voice navigation... Does this give turn by turn voice navigation...?

Comment: @Surbhit Thanvi Have you found anything for turn by turn voice navigation ?

Comment: Both of those code snippets provide turn by turn voice navigation, the `walking` value must be NO to get turn by turn driving directions.  If `walking` is YES, then you get walking directions.

Answer (score 2):

I built ontop of progrmr's answer above...the code below will take a NSString input of an address then forward Geocode it and then open the Maps app with voice navigated directions to the NSString input.  The NameString and PhoneString get attached to the placemark put on the Maps app.  The code below would not be possible with out progrmr's code above, please mark his answer as useful.

```
    [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:AddressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D there = location.coordinate;

            MKPlacemark *destPlace = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:there addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem *destMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destPlace];
            destMapItem.name = NameString;
            destMapItem.phoneNumber = PhoneString;

            NSArray* mapItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destMapItem, nil];
            NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];
            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Does this have turn by turn voice navigation?

Comment: Yes, it does have turn by turn voice navigation on devices that support that feature.